# How to hide the values in jquery choosen dropdownlistbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview

Hi I am developing one jquery application where I have one choosen dropdownlistbox and gridview. The first column of gridview contains checkboxes and at the top it also contains check all button. For example if I check 3 rows inside the gridview then corresponding values in dropdownlistbox i need to disable. I am trying as below.
This is the code to get all the cheked values from gridview.

```
var checkedValues = [];
        $("#<%=gdvRegretletter.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
            if($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true))
            {
                checkedValues += $(this).val();
            }
        });
```

Once i get values in array and when i go to dropdown i have below code.

```
 $('.limitedNumbSelect').change(function (e) {

        $("#limitedNumbSelect > option").each(function () {
         //if (this.value == checkedValues)  If this.value is equal to any value from checkedValues then i want to hide that value inside dropdownlistbox.

            // Here i want to hide all values of checkedValues array(values will be same in dropdownlistbox)
        });
});
```

I tried as below.

```
$('.limitedNumbSelect').change(function (e) {
            var checkedValues = [];
            $("#<%=gdvRegretletter.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
                 if ($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true)) {
                     checkedValues.push($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text().trim());
                 }
             });
             $(".limitedNumbSelect > option").each(function () {
                 var val = $(this).val();
                 alert(val);
                 var display = checkedValues.indexOf(val) === -1;
                 $(this).toggle(display);
                 $('.limitedNumbSelect option[value=' + display + ']').hide();
                 $(".limitedNumbSelect").find('option:contains(' + display + ')').remove().end().chosen();
             });
        });
```

In above code there is one bug. For example if i select one value from gridview then if i click on dropdown i am able to select that value(on first click). On second click required value will hide.

Above code does not work. Array checkedValues doesnt catch values.

I am unable to figure out what to write inside. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('.limitedNumbSelect').change(function (e) {
    $("#limitedNumbSelect > option").each(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var display = checkedValues.indexOf(val) === -1;
        $(this).toggle(display);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Problem is  $("#<%=gdvRegretletter.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
            if($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true))
            {
                checkedValues += $(this).val();
            }
        }); This does not works.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line:

```
checkedValues += $(this).val();
```

In this line:

```
checkedValues.push($(this).val());
```

Comment: Hi thank you. this works. Problem is as soon as i select some option from the dropdownlist immediately corresponding value will be hidden. Whenever i click on drodpwn it will not hide. Should i use click event before iterating through options?